# how to create the dropdown box with select and nonselect checkbox just like in the below image using angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs

[image]

Please help me to implement the below image in dropdown using angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to solve it using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. IMO I think radio buttons are made for situations where only one value can be selected, checkbox are for multiple states.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.cars = [
    {
      type: 'Audi',
      selected: 'false'
    },
    {
      type: 'BMW',
      selected: 'true'
    },
    {
      type: 'Bentley',
      selected: 'false'
    },
    {
      type: 'Ferrari',
      selected: 'true'
    },
    {
      type: 'Ford',
      selected: 'false'
    },
    {
      type: 'Porsche',
      selected: 'false'
    }
  ];
  $scope.nonSelectedChange = function(){
    $scope.nonSelected = $scope.cars.filter(function(x){return x.selected=='false'}).length;
  };
  $scope.nonSelectedChange();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
       
    <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <td><input type="radio" ng-model="car.selected" value="true" ng-change="nonSelectedChange()"/></td>
      <td><input type="radio" ng-model="car.selected" value="false" ng-change="nonSelectedChange()"/></td>
      <td>{{car.type}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can u help me to done the same concepts inside the dropdown

Comment: Hi @Marcus Hoglund can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741144/how-to-create-the-filter-in-the-search-list-using-angular-js

Comment: the same concepts as above should be implemented in the existing code

Comment: @Prasad Please accept or upvote this answer if it helped u

Comment: please help me with above comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dropdown list, based on an object or an array in AngularJS, you should use the ng-options directive

You can also use the ng-repeat directive to make the same dropdown list

Dropdowns made with ng-options allows the selected value to be an object, while dropdowns made from ng-repeat has to be a string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="y.brand for (x, y) in cars">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>

<p>The visible text inside the dropdown list can also be a property of the value object.</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi can I able to change the colour of the text when it get selected or non selected